# How to add a StackPanel in a Button in C# code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

How to add a **StackPanel** in a Button using c# code behind (i.e. convert the following XAML to C# )? There is no `Button.Children.Add`...

```
<Button>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
      <Image Source="foo.png"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set `Button.Content` instead of using `Button.Children.Add`

As a longer explanation:

- Button is a control which "only has 1 child" - its `Content`.
- Only very few controls (generally "Panels") can contain a list of zero or more `Children` - e.g. StackPanel, Grid, WrapPanel, Canvas, etc.

---

As your code already shows, you can set the `Content` of a Button to be a Panel - this would ehn allow you to then add multiple child controls. However, really in your example, then there is no need to have the StackPanel as well as the Image. It seems like your StackPanel is only adding Padding - and you could add the Padding to the Image rather than to the StackPanel if you wanted to.

Answer (score 25):

```
  Image img = new Image();
  img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("foo.png"));

  StackPanel stackPnl = new StackPanel();
  stackPnl.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
  stackPnl.Margin = new Thickness(10);
  stackPnl.Children.Add(img);

  Button btn = new Button();
  btn.Content = stackPnl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
<Window.Resources>   
    <ImageSource x:Key="LeftMenuBackgroundImage">index.jpg</ImageSource>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="LeftMenuBackgroundImageBrush" 
     ImageSource="{DynamicResource LeftMenuBackgroundImage}"/> 
</Window.Resources>
```

and in Codebehind

```
Button btn = new Button();
        btn.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        btn.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        StackPanel stk = new StackPanel();
        stk.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        stk.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
        stk.SetResourceReference(StackPanel.BackgroundProperty, "LeftMenuBackgroundImageBrush");
        btn.Content = stk;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Xaml :

```
<Button x:Name="Btn" Click="Btn_Click" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
  <StackPanel>
     <Image Source="foo.png" Height="16" Width="16"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

In C# :

```
Button btn = new Button();
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
Image img = new Image
{
   Source = "../foo.png"
}
panel.Children.Add(img);
btn.Content = panel;
```

I advise you to put the image in xaml resources :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="Img" UriSource="/Img/foo.png"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And call it like this :

```
Image img = new Image
{
   Source = (BitmapImage)FindResource("Img")
};
```